# Can one use "...at at least..."?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have to use a particular sentence which is:

***They differ at at least one position.***

Is this the correct use of at least? Is my sentence correct?

Comment: ***At least:*** According to the lowest possible assessment; not less than. They differ at least one position ( from each other/one another).

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? Your question title is different from your example sentence, where  "at" is written twice, was that intentional or a typo? If you want to know if "*atleast*" is one or two words, could you please ask that. I'm sorry but proofreading is off topic on EL&U, unless you explain the source of your confusion.

Comment: Please visit this page, http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic questions that show research and whose answer cannot be found in any online dictionary will always attract upvotes, attention and good answers.

Comment: I've found myself using that wording.  Whether it's "correct" or not is hard to say.  It's certainly not "nonsense".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "They differ in at least one position."

or

> "Regarding at least one issue -- *the issue* -- they take different positions."

or if there are are few disagreements:

> "Though they agree in most ways, their positions are different on at least one issue."

Answer (score 3):

The "at at least" word string is not inherently impossible. For example:

> Her little dog, Toto, has snapped at at least three bicyclists in the past month.

As other answerers have pointed out, the phrase "differ at" may sound less natural than "differ on" or "differ in" in the sentence "They differ in/on/at/from at least one position," depending on what the position in question refers to. Still, I can imagine a scenario where "differ at" might be the strongest choice. Suppose that you are comparing two baseball teams that have similar strengths and weaknesses, except that one has a much better third baseman than the other. Then you might sum up your comparison by saying

> Both teams are strong up the middle, have serviceable starting rotations and excellent relievers, hit for power but not average, and have a fairly strong bench. They differ at at least one position, however: third base.

Comment: I came across this Q when Word complained about my "perform a measurement at at least two [...] azimuths". It stops complaining, when "at least" is parenthesized by commas, but I see, you haven't used them. Could you verify that they are indeed not needed?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: Not only are the commas not needed for sense or to indicate a natural pause, but I think adding them would be harmful to the intended sense of your sentence. To me, the phrase "at least" set off by commas suggests "to say the least" or "by way of compensation"—but what you mean is simply "no fewer than." In this case, ignoring Word's automated preferences is the way to go; or you could change "at least" to "no fewer than," if you dislike the abutting "at"s.

Comment: Thanks, +1; it's a shame this Q was not so well received. The internet is full of contradicting pieces of info on this matter.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: The desirability of using the same word consecutively is a matter of taste, I think. There is even a rhetorical term for doing it intentionally for effect: [anadiplosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis) (though the words repeated in anadiplosis tend to be nouns and verbs, and occur at the end and beginning of separate clauses). Word is automatically suspicious of word repeats because more often than not they occur as a result of typing errors. But in the right context, using the same word twice without intervening punctuation is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "They differ on at least one position."
eg " Jim and I differ on this point."

You can develop this by saying, for example, "Alice and LiMei differ inasmuch as Alice never goes to concerts."